# ¿Cómo seleccionar un elemento que tiene varias clases usando css?

Tags: html, css3

Pues lo dicho en la pregunta, supongamos que tenemos el siguiente escenario:

```
<h1 class="elemento1 elemento2 elemento3"></h1>
<h2 class="elemento2"></h2>
<a class="elemento3" href="#"></a>
```

Y yo quiero hacer un selector css, que me actúe solo en los elementos html, que tienen las clases "elemento1 elemento2 elemento3". Tened en cuenta que los selectores pueden ser diferentes no todos van a ser "h1". ¿Cómo podría hacerlo?

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Para seleccionarlo con css debes encadenar las clases: `.elemento1.elemento2.elemento3`  Si no pones espacios entre ellas cogerá solo los elementos que tengas las tres clases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La manera a la que estamos acostumbrados a usar los selectores CSS es esta:

**CSS**

```
.elemento1 .elemento2 .elemento3. {
    /*reglas css*/
}
```

De esta manera lo que dices es que busque un elemento con la clase **elemento3** que sea hijo de un elemento con la clase **elemento2** y que este a su vez sea hijo de un elemento con la clase **elemento1**.

Pero existe una manera para referirte al mismo elemento con varias clases y es tan simple como quitarle el espacio entre clases quedando así:

**CSS**

```
.elemento1.elemento2.elemento3. {
        /*reglas css*/
}
```